# How to distribute production percentage by multiple work centers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I can't find the right formula to distribute a production percentage when a product goes through multiple working centers.

I have my company production by weight, by percentage and by work center, so I can add all the percentages that belong to a specific work center.

Production by work center:
[image: Production by work center]

The formula I'm using is:

```
=sumif(column_of_workcenters,work_center,column_of_percentages)
```

With cell references it looks something like this:

```
=SUMAR.SI($H$44:$H$50,"*"&J44&"*",$G$44:$G$50)
```

Formula for sum:
[image: Formula for sum]

I have tried several combinations of count and sumifs formulas with no luck. I think the problem is the "sum if contains workcenter" approach.

If a product have multiple work centers assigned, they all add instead of distribute equally.

Current values:
[image: Current values]

It should be something like this:

Expected values:
[image: Expected values]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Enter

```
=SUMPRODUCT($G$44:$G$50,IF(IFERROR(FIND(J44,$H$44:$H$50,1),0)>0,1,0),2/(LEN($H$44:$H$50)+1))
```

in cell `K44` as an array formula (`CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`) then copy to `K45` and `K46`.

**Explanation**

For each of `a,b,c` the formula uses `SUMPRODUCT` to calculate:

```
SUM(PERCENT_IN_COLUMN_G × NUMERATOR ÷ DENOMINATOR)
```

NUMERATOR is `1` if say `a` is in column H and `0` if it is not there. In the formula this is handled by

```
IF(IFERROR(FIND(J44,$H$44:$H$50,1),0)>0,1,0)
```

DENOMINATOR is the number of letters in column H. Assuming that each entry in column H is a comma-delimited list of letters we can get the number of letters by

```
(LEN($H$44:$H$50)+1)/2
```

Since we want to divide by that value we use its reciprocal in the formula

```
2/(LEN($H$44:$H$50)+1)
```

So this formula should still work if you have `a,b,c,d` or whatever in column H.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a helper column, insert the following formula in `I44`:

```
=G44/(LEN(H44)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(H44,",",""))+1)
```

And populate down.

Then in `K44`, use:

```
=SUMIF(H44:H50,"*"&J44&"*",I44:I50)
```

And again, populate down (for every work centre)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as intended. I forgot to mention in the main post that I would rather avoid using a helper column.